# How to fix error running pod install during running iOS simulator in Android Studio?

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase, dart, cocoapods

I try to Run Flutter application through 'main.dart' in Android Studio.
But I found error belows.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A file_picker
      A firebase_storage
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - desktop_webview_auth
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_database
      - firebase_dynamic_links
      - flutter_facebook_auth
      - flutter_inappwebview
      - fluttertoast
      - geocoding
      - google_sign_in_ios
      - image_picker_ios
      - kakao_flutter_sdk_common
      - package_info_plus
      - shared_preferences_ios
      - sign_in_with_apple
      - twitter_login
      - webview_flutter_wkwebview

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `desktop_webview_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/desktop_webview_auth/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `file_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/file_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_database` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`
    firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_dynamic_links` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_dynamic_links/ios`
    firebase_dynamic_links: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
    firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_facebook_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_inappwebview` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_inappwebview/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `geocoding` from `.symlinks/plugins/geocoding/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `kakao_flutter_sdk_common` from `.symlinks/plugins/kakao_flutter_sdk_common/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `package_info_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sign_in_with_apple` from `.symlinks/plugins/sign_in_with_apple/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `twitter_login` from `.symlinks/plugins/twitter_login/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter_wkwebview` from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_1_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/2.30909.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_1_6_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.0.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.0.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.0.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.0.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.1.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.0.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.1.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.2.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.6/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.7/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.4.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.4.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.4.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.4.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.6/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.7/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.8/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.9/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.10/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.11/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.1.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.1.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.1.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.1.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.2.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.2.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.4.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.4.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.4.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.6/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.7/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.6.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.6.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.6.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.8.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.8.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.0-beta/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.0-beta2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.6/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.7/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.2.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.2.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.2.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_3_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/3/c/FBSDKLoginKit/15.1.0/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_8_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/8/6/OrderedSet/5.0.0/OrderedSet.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_5_1_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/5/1/0/Toast/4.0.0/Toast.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.2.4/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/Database (= 10.2.0)

      In Podfile:
        firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 10.0.5, which depends on
          Firebase/Database (= 10.3.0)

    Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Database (= 10.2.0), Firebase/Database (= 10.3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

So I tried to *arch -x86_64 pod install*, but it has error like belows.

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_dynamic_links: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Database (= 10.2.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 10.0.5, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 10.3.0)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Database (= 10.2.0), Firebase/Database (= 10.3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I tried to 'pod update' and 'pod install' also, but I couldn't solved yet.

this is my pod file. (platform :ios, '11.0')

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

How can I solve? please help me...

Comment: Try to delete the pod.lock file. Then reinstall pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **MUST NOT DELETE** *Podfile*, but only

**pubspec.lock**

**ios/Podfile.lock**

**ios/Pods** directory.

Then as you have Silicon mac execute

`flutter pub get`

`-x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

Comment: OMG... I already deleted my Podfile and been hanging around all day trying to fix this.

Comment: Yeah I see. Did you use git. If so you can revert this file using them. But I guarantee that I gave you 100% working solution.

Comment: yes, I am using git.

Comment: Then reverse Podfile. It is not a rocket science. Then do as I said. I am sure it works, if all things are done correctly. Finally kindly mark my answer accepted and upvote

Comment: In the end, I had no choice but to go back by creating a new branch by creating Git. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the pod, not from your Android Studio Terminal it got some Stuck error in Android Studio.
Install the pod Using the MAC OS terminal it will work fine for you.

**install Cocopods from terminal command**

sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

Comment: Yes. I stucked because I used Android Studio Termianl... I deleted Podfile and Podfile.lock, but that leads to me to the hell.